# DELETE request is not changing to GET on redirect

Tags: redirect, grails, grails-controller

I am sending `DELETE` type Ajax request to my delete method in my controller.
For successful delete, I am trying to redirect to another method in same controller that reloads the list and is of `GET` type.

Currently my delete operation is working fine with default status code 302,but on redirect, it is redirecting with `'Request Method: DELETE' instead of 'GET'` which is default behavior of **Grails**.

Kindly suggest the solution for it

```
redirect(action: 'list',controller:'dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a redirect you should be doing an http call rather than an Ajax call. The redirect is handled automatically by your browser so you can't change it from a delete to a get. You might try using a forward or making a separate call to the list in a callback/promise.

Alternatively if you want to keep it in one Ajax call, I would hope that your dashboard controller, list action would be calling a service to get it's data. So instead of doing a redirect I would call that services, and return that data.

I say hope because I've seen many examples, where people put business logic in controllers, where it doesn't belong, instead of moving it to a service, where it can be reused.